# Presenting modal dialogs from XIB in Cocoa: best/shortest pattern?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, modal-dialog, xib, nswindowcontroller

Below is my typical WindowController module for presenting a modal dialog (could be settings, asking username/password, etc) loaded from a XIB. It seems a bit too complex for something like this. Any ideas how this can be done better/with less code?

Never mind that it's asking for a password, it could be anything. What frustrates me most is that I repeat the same pattern in each and every of my XIB-based modal window modules. Which of course means I could define a custom window controller class, but before doing that I need to make sure this is really the best way of doing things.

```
#import "MyPasswordWindowController.h"

static MyPasswordWindowController* windowController;

@interface MyPasswordWindowController ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSSecureTextField *passwordField;
@end

@implementation MyPasswordWindowController
{
    NSInteger _dialogCode;
}

- (id)init
{
    return [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MyPassword"];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self.window center];
}

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [NSApp stopModalWithCode:_dialogCode];
    _dialogCode = 0;
}

- (IBAction)okButtonAction:(NSButton *)sender
{
    _dialogCode = 1;
    [self.window close];
}

- (IBAction)cancelButtonAction:(NSButton *)sender
{
    [self.window close];
}

+ (NSString*)run
{
    if (!windowController)
        windowController = [MyPasswordWindowController new];
    [windowController loadWindow];
    windowController.passwordField.stringValue = @"";
    if ([NSApp runModalForWindow:windowController.window])
        return windowController.passwordField.stringValue;
    return nil;
}
```

The application calls [MyPasswordWindowController run], so from the point of view of the user of this module it looks simple, but not so much when you look inside.

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JRG-Developer ask there too, thanks for pointing out. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37640/presenting-modal-dialogs-from-xib-in-cocoa-best-shortest-pattern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set tags on your buttons to distinguish them. Have them both target the same action method:

```
- (IBAction) buttonAction:(NSButton*)sender
{
    [NSApp stopModalWithCode:[sender tag]];
    [self.window close];
}
```

Get rid of your `_dialogCode` instance variable and `-windowWillClose:` method.

`-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]` will already center the window, so you can get rid of your `-awakeFromNib` method.

Get rid of the invocation of `-[NSWindowController loadWindow]`. That's an override point. You're not supposed to call it. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000031-BAJBGGGD) is clear on that point. It will be called automatically when you request the window controller's `-window`.

Get rid of the static instance of `MyPasswordWindowController`. Just allocate a new one each time. There's no point in keeping the old one around and it can be troublesome to reuse windows.

Comment: I posted an answer based on yours, with full source code here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37640/presenting-modal-dialogs-from-xib-in-cocoa-best-shortest-pattern